# How to find a point nearest neighbours in OpenVDB?

Tags: search, data-structures, tree, nearest-neighbor

Ther is an [example](http://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/codeExamples.html#sInterpolation) on how to find one nearest neighbor yet how to find all in a radious (or a box placing search begining into its centre if possible)?